# Virtuoso System Requirements

Tags: cpu, ram, virtuoso

We would be using Virtuoso for storing RDFs, the triple count will be 100 million to start with. I need to know what should be typical RAM, CPU, Disk etc for this. Querying will be with SPARQL and there will be a bit complex queries.

Kindly provide your inputs.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The average size of a Virtuoso version 6.x triple (quad) is about 30bytes thus for 100 million triples you would need about 3GB RAM , this being the most critical component to enable the database working set to fit in memory , data does not need to be loaded from disk once the database is "warmed up", for best performance. This would be especially the case when running complex queries. In terms of disk, the fast they are the quicker the databaase can be loaded into memory, checkpoints performed etc. thus SSDs or similar devices are recommended where possible, espcially if memory is limited and reading data from disk at times in unavoidable. In terms of processor standard commodity 64bit processor available today would suffice, typically running on a Linux x86_64 system of your choice, as said memory is always the most critical component though.

See the following Virtuoso FAQ and peformance tuning documents for more details:

http://virtuoso.openlinksw.com/dataspace/dav/wiki/Main/VirtRDFPerformanceTuning
http://virtuoso.openlinksw.com/dataspace/dav/wiki/Main/#FAQ

Comment: "With Virtuoso 7 you get 3 times the compression running in Column Store mode, which the RDF Quad Store runs in by default, so 10 bytes per Quad on average"
https://www.mail-archive.com/virtuoso-users@lists.sourceforge.net/msg06875.html